# Compare fields with same name of objects of different classes in Java

Tags: java

I have two objects, each of which have tens of fields:

```
Class1 {
    int firstProperty;
    String secondProperty;
    String anotherProperty1;
    ...
}

Class2 {
    int firstProperty;
    String secondProperty;
    String anotherProperty2;
    ...
}
```

some of the method names are exactly same, others are not, for example here, they all have `firstProperty` and `secondProperty` and they are same in name. but other fields are not same. What is an elegant way to know if the values of every same field of two objects of the two class is actually same?

_________________________________UPDATE_____________________________________

I'm still not sure why some people still think it is exactly the duplicate question. Since the question is closed, I have to paste my solution here.

```
private boolean hasChanged(Object o1, Object o2){

    if (o1 == null || o2 == null) {
        return true;
    }

    Class clazz1 = o1.getClass();
    Class clazz2 = o2.getClass();
    for (Method method1 : clazz1.getDeclaredMethods()) {
        for (Method method2 : clazz2.getDeclaredMethods()) {
            try {
                if (method1.getName().startsWith("get") && method1.getName().equals(method2.getName())) {
                    if (method1.invoke(o1, null) == null && method2.invoke(o2, null) == null) {
                        continue;
                    } else if (method1.invoke(o1, null) == null || method2.invoke(o2, null) == null) {
                        continue;
                    } else if (!method1.invoke(o1, null).equals(method2.invoke(o2, null))) {
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: There is definitely a better way to do what you are trying to do here, but you will have to use reflection and I don't see it being particularly elegant no matter the approach.

Comment: youve asked this a few hours ago?

Comment: Maybe nobody has told you yet: but asking the same question twice is a bad thing. Doing that within hours: even worse. The correct way: when you are unhappy with the answers from the other question - put up comments, ask for clarification, whatever. Maybe even accept the best you got so far. When you then write a new question - point to the old and and **clearly** express why another question is required! But just pointing up the same question again ... that is ... I better shut up now, to avoid getting flagged for being rude.

Comment: @GhostCat I'm sure it is different. Please reopen.

Comment: *What is an elegant way to know if the values of every same field of two objects of the two class is actually same?* vs. *I want to compare if the "similar" fields of objects of the two class actually have same values. What is the most elegant way to do this?* ... I am sure this is not different. Seriously: I will not re-open this question. Sure, when you find 5 people willing to vote for re-open ...  fine with me. But me - no way.

Comment: In other words: dont claim its different: **explain** why this question is not an almost exact copy of the other one. What is **different** here? I fail to see it.

Comment: @GhostCat the difference is the field name is the same in this case. I was wondering if there is any operation checking whether the value is same when two field name is equal.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best approach to this is to create a common abstract class that they both inherit from with an overridden `equals`. Something like this:

```
public abstract class ParentClass {
    int firstProperty;
    String secondProperty;
    String anotherProperty1;

    @Override
    public boolean equals(ParentClass other)  {
        return this.firstProperty == other.firstProperty &&
            this.secondProperty.equals(other.secondProperty) &&
            this.anotherProperty1.equals(other.anotherProperty1);
    }
}
```

Then just have your `Class1 extends ParentClass` and `Class2 extends ParentClass`. Then if you have an instance of class one, lets say: `Class1 a = new Class1();` and `Class2 b = new Class2();` you can do `a.equals(b)` to compare equality.